# .htaccess not working on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, mamp

My completed code in my only `.htaccess` file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule blue-world.pl/([a-z]+)(?:/([a-z]+))? index.php?nav=$1#$2
```

I need to redirect `blue-world.pl/name/name2` to `blue-world.pl?nav=name#name2`. How to do this to make it working **BOTH**: localhost and server.

When in MAMP i try to type: `localhost/scregal.blue-world.pl/title` i see:

```
The requested URL /scregal.blue-world.pl/title was not found on this server.
```

Below is my file hierarchy in localhost:

```
scregal.blue-world.pl
    - .htaccess
    - index.php -> var_dump($_GET)
```

In the `httpd.conf` there are following lines:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ index.php?nav=$1#$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: So what may be wrong with mine? i just copied and pasted Your code.

Comment: my mistake, there is not 'git' keyword in name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67976/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-anubhava).